# How to connect EMR Cluster to EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-emr

I use spark to compute parallelise tasks. In order to do it, my project is connected to a server that produces some data I need to start my spark job.

Now I would like to migrate my project to the cloud on aws.

I got my spark app on EMR and my server on EC2. How can I make my EMR spark app able to use http request on my EC2 server? Do I need something like a gateway?

Thanks,

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EMR cluster actually runs on EC2 servers. You can always ssh to those servers. And then surely you can ssh to another ec2 server from emr ec2 server

Comment: You are right, but I was not accurate enough... I would like to use http from EMR to call an api on EC2. I'm not sure SSH is the solution, is it? I only know ssh as a way to use a machine that is away. I'll edit my post in order to make it more accurate.

Comment: http is much more easier; all you need is make an http request ( using curl/wget ) from ur EMR EC2 server to ur other EC2 server ( where u would have hosted ur http end point)

Comment: You mean EMR and EC2 instance already know each other? I thought there was some kind of tuning to get them on the same network. Ok, thank you for the answer, i'll check that. Have a nice day.

Comment: well all u need to do is start your EMR cluster and EC2 instance inside same vpc group.  Anyway for http; even that is not needed if u expose port 80 to right ip addresses.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, you should use `ssh hadoop@ec2-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com -i /path/mykeypair.pem` instead of `ssh -i /path/mykeypair.pem -ND 8157 hadoop@ec2-###-##-##-###-.compute.amazonaws.com`. The second command has no response.